# GKGameCenterViewController analog in ios 5?

Tags: ios, game-center

`iOS 6` provides new view controller to display Game Center info: `GKGameCenterViewController`.

Does `iOS 5.1` provide something similar (`except separate controllers for Leader-board and Achievements)`?

Comment: no, it doesn't. but you can make it yourself

Comment: Thank you. I just needed for somebody to confirm that.

Comment: Is it possible then please can you show code here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handle both the old and new GameCenter APIs in my app which supports everything between iOS 4 and 7.

I started with the GameCenterManager.m sample code.

1) In GameCenterManager.m, I changed authenticateLocalUser

```
- (void) authenticateLocalUser
{
    if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
    {

        if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] respondsToSelector: @selector(setAuthenticateHandler:)]) {

             [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {

                 [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processGameCenterAuth:error:) withArg: viewcontroller error: error];

             })];
         } else {


            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
            {
                [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processOldGameCenterAuth:) error: error];
            }];
         }
    }
}
```

2) And then in my main view controller, here are my two versions of the authentication handler.

```
- (void) processOldGameCenterAuth: (NSError*) error; {
    // for iOS < 6.0 without the viewcontroller parameter

    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
        usingGamecenter = TRUE;
        [self.gameCenterManager reloadHighScoresForCategory: kOverallLeaderboard];
    } else {
        usingGamecenter = FALSE;
    }
    // *** this is where you update your UI after game center login
}

- (void) processGameCenterAuth: (UIViewController*) gameCenterController error: (NSError*) error; {
    if (gameCenterController) {
        [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self processOldGameCenterAuth: error];
    }
}
```